# NO video file was saved by using Python and OpenCV on my Raspberry PI

Tags: python, linux, opencv, python-2.7, raspberry-pi

I have two pieces of codes. Here is the first one. It was mainly copied from [save a video section](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#display-video) on OpenCV-Python tutorial website, but I modified a little bit.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(7,200)
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('X','V','I','D'), 20.0, (640,480))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        out.write(frame)
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Second one is here:

```
import cv
cv.NamedWindow('camera',1)
cap = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
fps = 20
fourcc = cv.CV_FOURCC('X','V','I','D')
cv.SetCaptureProperty(cap,cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT,200)
out = cv.CreateVideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc,fps,(640,480))
while True
    img = cv.QueryFrame(out,img)
    cv.WriteFrame(out,img)
    cv.ShowImage('camera',img)
    if cv.WaitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cv.DestroyAllWindows()
```

Neither of them can make a video file saved or destroy the window in the end. No errors occurred in shell after running the code. I used Python 2.7.6 and OpenCV 2.3.1. Can somebody help me? Thanks a lot.

PS: I am not sure whether my method to set frame numbers correct or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may have several reasons. Check the following:

- Check that you can encode with XVID, maybe try with MJPEG first.
- Set width and height of your input video by `cap.set(3,640)` and `cap.set(4,480)`

Comment: Thank you for answering me. So is it mainly about the fourcc codec? Can I set the frame number by using `cap.set(7,200)`?

Comment: It should be about the codec and the parameters. The `cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT` or that 7 parameter is just a constant that you can get to see the number of frames in the video. You cannot set it like that. If you want to capture 200 frames, just define a number and break the while as it gets to 200.